# System.NullReferenceException When checking if != null

Tags: c#, null, handler, ashx, argumentnullexception

I'm using an ASHX handler, i want the handler to check if Session != null.

```
if (context.Session["Username"] != null)
```

And i get this error pointing this line:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (context.Session["Username"] != null)
```

Does your handler implement [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)? Otherwise Session might not be available.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx):

> Specifies that the target HTTP handler
>   requires read and write access to
>   session-state values. This is a marker
>   interface and has no methods.

Comment: Oh stupid me,

I should have add `IReadOnlySessionState`...

I found this link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use it like this. One of the encapsulating objects may be already null:

```
if (context != null)
  if (context.Session != null)
    if (context.Session["Username"] != null) {
      // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: It is always safer to stack null checks like the one above, so that you can pinpoint the exact source of the problem. Seems like a chore but pays off.

Comment: this approach is reasonable if there is an alternate code path if Session is not available - on the other hand if it is a hard assumption to expect the Session to be there and your code *depends* on this assumption, the **fail fast** approach would be to just let it throw an exception, otherwise chances are you are masking this problem with a null check.

Comment: Well of course nested if statements should be complemented with nested else's, where it would be suitable to deal with a null object (which shouldn't be null in the first place) and throw a proper exception with a proper message.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I'd say that check to see if the context is not null first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an .ashx file.  The solution was that the handler has to implement IReadOnlySessionState (for read-only access) or IRequiresSessionState  (for read-write access). eg:

```
public class myModule: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState { ... }
```

These Interfaces do not need any additional code but act as markers for the framework.

Hope that this helps.

Jonathan