# how to create session in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview which shows the details of passenger who have booked their ticket
on page load event i have following code.

```
Label1.Text = Session("Pid").ToString()
    Dim Sql As String = "select * from Plist where Pid='" & Label1.Text & "'"
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = strCon
        Dim cm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, con)
        con.Open()
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()

        End If
    End Try
```

I am getting this error:
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Where did you declare and instantiate `con`?

Comment: and where did you declare Session("Pid") ?

Comment: You should print your stack trace here as it will help to know exactly where the exception is being thrown from.

Answer (score 3):

the session `Session("Pid")` is null, you should fill it with data before and you also should check the session:

```
If Session("Pid") IsNot Nothing Then
' write your code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all your "SESSIONS" for null before using it...................

And **[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774248/system-nullreferenceexception-when-checking-if-null)**

and also **[IRequiresSessionState Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)**

Specifies that the target HTTP handler requires read and write access to session-state values. This is a marker interface and has no methods.