# Running debug vs 2019 setting session variable returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session-variables

I have been having trouble with inProc session variables returning null. The most current is trying to set a Session Variable in the PageLoad of Default. Here is my code.

```
   string NameNew = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    if (NameNew.Contains('\\'))
    {
        NameNew = NameNew.Split('\\').Last();
    }
    if (Session != null)
    {
        Session["UsersName"] = NameNew;
    }
```

When debugging it returns System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have tried updating vs, checking IIS express for session issues, moved other session objects to base class. I am at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to session? Which line exactly is it throwing on, because any of Page.User.Identity.Name could be null and cause this error

Comment: Session["UsersName"] = NameNew; is throwing the exception.

Comment: Is `Session` null at that point?

Comment: Flydog57 No it's not.

Comment: It's answered here I bet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774248/system-nullreferenceexception-when-checking-if-null?rq=1

Comment: Porco encapsulated in both  if (Context != null) and if (Context.Session != null) same result.

Comment: @Doug Farrell, can you provide the initial string about NameNew? Also, have you defined the session before it? If so, please provide the related code about session.